# How to 'zip' two or more coroutine channels?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So in RxJava, we could simply do:

```
Observable.zip(someObservable, anotherObservable, BiFunction { a, b -> //do something }.subscribe { // do something }
```

How do we do the same thing with Kotlin Coroutine Channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not ideal solution but it seems to work

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
private fun <T, R> CoroutineScope.zipChannels(
    channel1: ReceiveChannel<T>,
    channel2: ReceiveChannel<T>,
    zip: (T, T) -> R
): ReceiveChannel<R> = produce {
    val iterator1 = channel1.iterator()
    val iterator2 = channel2.iterator()
    while (iterator1.hasNext() && iterator2.hasNext()) {
        val value1 = iterator1.next()
        val value2 = iterator2.next()
        send(zip(value1, value2))
    }
    channel1.cancel()
    channel2.cancel()
    close()
}
```

**Update**

Also, there is a deprecated operator [zip](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/zip.html)

Comment: so to combine channel we need another channel. Is there no official way of doing it? but this make alot of sense.

Comment: I think that later we'll use more flows than channels. Flow has "zip" operator out of the box. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/

Comment: but flows are cold streams. What should we do for hot streams?

Comment: yep, you are right. I completely forgot about that. But look what I've found https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/zip.html

Comment: I think I understand now why such operators are only defined in flows. Its because flows as cold streams is enough just like RxJava Observables are cold streams and is enough for almost all use case. Channels on the other hand would only be used as low level and for some other use case.

Comment: yep, it might be. But for me, it's pretty strange that zip operator on hot streams will be deprecated due to zip operator on cold streams.

Comment: I think its coz of this https://medium.com/@elizarov/kotlin-flows-and-coroutines-256260fb3bdb. Well not directly related but still related.